where did AWS::Core::Policy go in Ruby v3?
Previously I could create a policy like:
AWS::Core::Policy.new.allow(:resource => some_arn, :principals => some_users, :actions => some_actions)
However, since upgrading the Ruby sdk v3, there is no longer a Policy class under Core. so, where did this go, how do I create a policy object?

If you were using v1 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v1/api/AWS/Core/Policy.html then that has moved to Aws::IAM::Policy since v2
here's the current v3 documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/IAM/Policy.html
